# GraphQL access to HttpRequest on a mutation function

Tags: java, graphql, graphql-java

Hi I'm new to GraphQL.

I want to migrate an existing endpoint to a GraphQL endpoint (Java). 
In oder to proceed with the application logic of the endpoint, I need the `HttpServletRequest` object.

How can I have access to `HttpServletRequest` object inside a mutation function?
I try to pass it as a parameter but I have to declare a `HttpServetRequest` Type.

Is there a way of having access to the above object inside a mutation? 
Is there a way of declaring Types of external libraries?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is normally done using the shared context. When executing an operation, you can pass an arbitrary object that will be accessible to all the `Datafetcher`s (resolvers), via `DataFetchingEnvironment#getContext`.

E.g.

```
GraphQLContext sharedContext = GraphQLContext.newContext()
    //this is where you pass any object you need
    //use other factory methods as needed
    .of(HttpServletRequest.class, servletRequest)
    .build();

graphQL.execute(ExecutionInput.newExecutionInput()
    .query(operation)
    .context(sharedContext)
    .build());
```

For older graphql-java versions:

```
graphQL.execute(query, context);
```

and later in the `DataFetcher` of your query/mutation:

```
HttpServletRequest request = environment.getGraphQlContext().get(HttpServletRequest.class);
```

This is also the common way to perform authorization: you pass in the user object via the context.

Comment: When using execute(ExecutionInput.newExecutionInput() I'm getting :
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: graphql.GraphQL.execute(Lgraphql/ExecutionInput;)Lgraphql/ExecutionResult;

While execute("my query") returns the expected result.

Comment: @alobar You must be using some older version of graphql-java then. In that case, just use the appropriate overload of the `execute` method that accepts a context. See the updated answer.

Comment: @alobar Did that answer your question?

Comment: First of all thank for you valuable answers. Unfortunately when I try to run .execute(query, context) I 'm getting that this function is deprecated. The version of graphql-java I'm using is 6.0

Comment: @alobar You have a dependency conflict then. You build with v6 and run with some other version. Analyse your dependency tree and figure it out. v6 definitely does have a method I exemplified first.

Comment: I am using this tutorial : [link] (https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-java/0-introduction/). 
So I have a class with `@WebServlet` annotation that extends `SimpleGraphQLServlet`. This is where I bulid my schema that is defined though SDL. I have a Query class which implements `GraphQLRootResolver`. Inside the method that returns my data, along with other parameteres I added a final parameter `DataFetchingEnvironment environment` to the method signature and through that I was able to access `HttpServletRequest`.

Comment: how to replace the deprecated 'getContext()' in a way that it works with custom context builders? 'getGraphQlContext()' is not compatible with a custom context object.. or: if the custom context is not needed anymore , how to get the request from env.getGraphQlContext() ? Searched almost everywhere, didn't find a solution yet :-(

Comment: @chriszichrisz `GraphQLContext` is just a map, you can put anything you want in there.  It doesn't limit you in any way. E.g. `GraphQLContext ctx = GraphQLContext.newContext().of(ServletRequest.class, servletRequest).build()` I used a class as the key, but any object will work. Btw I updated the answer to reflect this.